# How to match a character at nth position (Cloudera Impala SQL)

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I am trying to replace a character at a specific position in SQL. I would like to replace the 15th character in a string like this: `2019-07-08 06:56:00`

The SQL code I have is as such:

```sql
regexp_replace(cast(date_trunc('minute', from_unixtime(mtc.conversion_timestamp)) as string), 'REGEX', '0')
```

I've tried regex like this: `^.{6}` but it gives me all of the characters from 0-6. I need to just match a SINGLE character at the 15th position. Therefore, the match for `2019-07-08 06:56:00` should be 6 (from 56).

Basically, I would like to turn `2019-07-08 06:56:00` to `2019-07-08 06:50:00`

I've tried looking everywhere, but cannot figure it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you trying to replace or extract it?

Comment: Why not use date functions?  `SUBSTRING` or `LIKE` would work – but if you are using this on dates, use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to replace a character.

Comment: @Mitch I need the datetime to be in a String, so I figured regexp_replace would be the simplest solution

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Impala. It seems like regexp_replace is the only way I can replace a character in a string. (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html)

Comment: Then use `^(.{14}).` and replace with `\1<your replace string>`. Probably, `regexp_replace(col, '^(.{14}).', '\\1§')` to replace with `§`

Answer (score 0):

Update: `.(.{3}$)` this worked for what I was looking for.